# Trace of $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ space is $W^{k-1/p,p}(\partial \Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, trace

I was reading about abstract trace space of $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$. They have defined it as

$$W^{1/2,2}(\partial \Omega)=W^{1,2}(\Omega)/W_0^{1,2}(\Omega).$$

Similary I thought we can define abstract trace space of $W^{K,p}(\Omega)$ as
$$W^{k-1/p,p}(\partial \Omega)=W^{k,p}(\Omega)/W_0^{k,p}(\Omega).$$

Defining abstractly I can understand but the exponent where the author thought I don't have any idea.

Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Googling _trace theorem_ should help. This theorem gives another, direct definition of $W^{k-1/p,p}(\partial \Omega)$ (as Sobolev-Slobodecki spaces) and shows the equivalence. In this way, you can see what the first index means (it's the order of differentiability).